# How to import postgresql in Datagrip?

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

For some reason I am unable to import postgresql database in datagrip. I have dumped the database using Datagrip, but when I try to import it into another DB, it creates a new table with unknown columns.

Comment: Have you used og_dump for dumping? Do you use pg_restore for import?

Comment: I used datagrips' import and export feature by right clicking on the database. Didn't use pg_restore.

Comment: Please try: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/export-data.html#create-a-full-data-dump-for-mysql-and-postgresql